# Insert Dynamic PHP form into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic

I have a form which is dynamic and user can add more rows to insert different hours, I wonder which is the best way to add those data to MySQL database.

```
<input style="margin-left:28px;" type="image" class="add_field_button" src="img/add.png" />
<table id="dataTable" width="900" style="margin-left:25px; margin-top:10px;">
    <tr style="text-align:center;">
        <td width="70">From</td>
        <td>To</td>
        <td>Duration Hours</td>
        <td>Code</td>
        <td>Remark</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr style="height:85px; text-align:center;">
        <td><input type="text" name="hours1[]" id="hours1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="hours2[]" id="hours2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="durationh[]" id="durationh" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="hrscode[]" id="hrscode" /></td>
        <td><textarea name="remark[]" id="remark"></textarea></td>

    </tr> 
</table>
```

Inputs are expandable so I don't know how many rows they will send to save in `mysql`.

Comment: Can you post also related server code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't try because I didn't know where to start really. I'm kinda confused

Comment: Let's start with recieving your form in php and forget about mysql. When you are sure, you have all fields in backend, then start thinking of persistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), using the key to bind the input groupings together

```
foreach($_POST['hours1'] as $key => $value) { // could use any of the fields in $_POST['hours1']
    //$_POST['hours1'][$key];
    //$_POST['hours2'][$key];
    //$_POST['durationh'][$key];
    //$_POST['hrscode'][$key];
    //$_POST['remark'][$key];

    //INSERT INTO table (columns) VALUES (your $_POST values)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, Do I need to do one by one or can do all together?

Comment: You can do it all together. by using `as $key => $value` and `[$key]` you can link all your input groups together. So if you have 3 of each input name, the  `foreach()` will loop 3 times, and you will get each field in the same place/order.

Comment: `foreach($_POST['hours1'] as $key => $value) {
 $gfrom = $_POST['hours1'][$key];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO generalreport (`ID`, `from`) VALUES ('$id' ,'$gfrom')"); ` This only insert first value not others

Comment: Well that is because you are only inserting 2 columns/values, and neither of those `(ID,from)`/`('$id' ,'$gfrom')` have any relation to your posted fields - `hours1`/`hours2`/`durationh`/`hrscode`/`remark`. So how can it insert the other values if you don't include them in your query?

Comment: `foreach($_POST['hours1'] as $key => $value) {
 $gfrom = $_POST['hours1'][$key];
 $gto = $_POST['hours2'][$key];
 $gduration = $_POST['durationh'][$key];
 $gcode = $_POST['hrscode'][$key];
 $gremark = $_POST['gremark'][$key];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO generalreport (`ID`, `from`, `to`, `durationhours`, `code`, `remark`) VALUES ('$id' ,'$gfrom','$gto','$gduration','$gcode','$gremark')");

}` still doesn't work

Comment: I am not sure what `still doesn't work` means. That is very vague. Do you mean that it does not insert any rows? you might need to use a `or die(mysql_error())` at the end of your query to debug. Do you mean that it only inserts 1 row? Then you might want to do a `print_r($_POST)` to check if your dynamically expanded inputs are actually in array form.